# Tranformations of Numpy Array, Pass values to function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to take a numpy array and feed it into a constraint problem.

The table that I am working with is below -

```
Type1   2   3   4   5   6
A   0   1   1   0   1   1
B   0   1   1   0   1   1
C   0   0   1   1   1   1
D   0   0   1   1   1   1
E   1   1   1   1   0   1
F   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

When I transform the table into an array, I am trying to do two things:

1) Add 6 more columns (would be headers 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12). The new columns would have the exact same values of columns 1-6 for each type (A, B, C, etc...)

2) For each type, I am trying to pass the values into a constraint method. So for example I'd like to pass (x, y) where x is the type ("a") and y are the columns where value = 1. In other words the first (x, y) would be ("a", [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12])

(for step #1 it may not be necessary to create columns 7-12 if I had the ability to just add 6 to existing "true" values columns 1-6)

I have tried using nditer but I am confused on how to hold on to the "Type" in a nditer, do a boolean check on the value and then pass the column name? I was thinking that I would not even use the column name and just use a counter to come up with the y variable.

Comment: Forget `nditer`; it's a specialized iterator, more useful when developing compiled code, than general purpose `numpy` work.  `column names` aren't applicable in `numpy`.  Rows and columns are indenfied by positional index, not names.

Comment: Could you take a step back and provide some more explanation? What is your broader goal here? What do you mean when you say “if i had the ability to add 6 to existing...” Is your data stored in a pandas DataFrame? Why do you have a column named “Type”, can you change that? Are all your values 0 or 1, are they representing booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using apply and tile like below
the `np.tile` function repeats the array with boolean index

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], ['B', 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], ['C', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], ['D', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], ['E', 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], ['F', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], columns=('Type', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'))

def constraint(x, y):
    print("x: ", x)
    print("y: ", y)
    return x

df.apply(lambda row: constraint(row[0], np.arange(2*len(row[1:]))[np.tile((row[1:]==1),2)]+1), axis=1)
```

OR using loop like below

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    row=df.iloc[i]
    constraint(row[0], np.arange(2*len(row[1:]))[np.tile((row[1:]==1),2)]+1)
```